# Source for teaching that God judges non-Jews with a lower standard

Tags: gentiles, haftarah

I remember reading a Haftorah which I think was from one of the 12 minor prophets -- I'm not sure -- in which God tells the Jewish people something to the effect that His standard for judging the non-Jew will be considerably lower than for the Jew.  Does anyone recall that Haftorah?

Comment: Somewhat related - on the "opposite" spectrum, I believe that regarding prayers / requests, non-Jews are granted their requests more easily and quikly than Jews are.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Double AA for narrowing it down for me.  The pasuk is [Amos 3:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16175#v=2&showrashi=true), "Only you did I love above all the families of the earth; therefore, I will visit upon you all your iniquities [but not the gentiles]."  Originally I read the Art Scroll translation and commentary, I don't have it available right now, and I think either their elucidation or commentaries made clear what I put in the brackets, but which is less obvious in the JTS or the Hertz translations.  Rabbi Abbahu, at [Avoda Zara 4a](http://halakhah.com/rst/nezikin/35a%20-%20Avodoh%20Zoroh%20-%202a-35b.pdf) explains the verse by a parable:  "To what may it be compared? To a man who is the creditor of two persons, one of them a friend, the other an enemy; of his friend he will accept payment little by little, whereas of his enemy he will exact payment in one sum!"  In other words, God punishes us frequently to remind us to obey His commandments, and He does this out of love for us.  Non-Jews, however, are given no warnings of their oversight in obeying even the seven mitzvot of the sons of Noah, and although their task is easier, their punishment will be greater if they didn't live up to their task.